# Renombrado masivo de ficheros windows

Tags: windows10, powershell

necesito cambiar la extensión de varios ficheros que se encuentran en una carpeta la cual tiene más de 5000 ficheros repartidos en subcarpetas.

Estoy utlizando la PowerShell de W10.

los ficheros tienen este formato:

> fichero.js@ver=1.0
>
> otrofichero.js@ver=1.3.4
>
> otro.css@ver=2.0
>
> ...

necesito eliminar todo a partir de la "@" (incluida)

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*@ver=*" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "@ver=","" } -Whatif
```

Ejecutando este comando (sin la opción -Whatif), elimina la cadena indicada, pero se quedan con la siguiente forma

fichero.js1.0

No encuentro una opción que elimine los caracteres a partir de uno indicado.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Carl,

Siguiendo con tu intento, una forma de encarar lo que indicas es utilizar el método **split**, para particionar el nombre, definiendo el "@" como punto de corte (o separador). Así podrás quedarte con la primer parte, de la siguiente manera:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*@ver=*" -Recurse |  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.split("@")[0]}
```

Puedes probar con el parámetro **-Whatif**, como lo estabas haciendo para validar.